# A typical local rule requires a mailbox to be offset the entire width of a shoulder off the road

Tags: meaning-in-context

I don't understand the meaning of the verb "offset (to counterbalance, counteract, or compensate for) in the following context.

"A typical local rule requires a mailbox to be offset the entire width of a shoulder off the road with an addition of a specific number of inches."

Here is the [link] (https://legalbeagle.com/5598432-rules-moving-mailbox.html)

Answer (score 1):

It's related to this definition found at [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/offset?s=t)

Surveying. to establish (a line) parallel to a main survey line at an offset.

In this case, it means to place or locate the mailbox several inches away from the edge of the shoulder of the road IF the road is unimproved AKA doesn't have a curb.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! In this case does the following phrase make sense if we replace "offset" with "survey"?

"A typical local rule requires a mailbox to be surveyed the entire width of a shoulder off the road with an addition of a specific number of inches." Thank you once again and sorry for the late response!

Answer (score 0):

The word "offset" is a compound of "off" and "set". To "set" means to place. For example:

> Set the bowl on the table.

or

> Set the post in concrete.

The word "off" means away from some relevant location. Examples:

> Take the bowl off the table.

or

> Anyone who is not a player should get off the court.

or

> The picture over the mantle is off center.

Therefore, to offset something means to "set" or place it at a location which is "off" or away from some point of reference.

Comment: Thank you so very much for the explanation and so sorry for the very late response!